# How can I have apollo-module automatically refetch queries on query param updates

Tags: javascript, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, hasura

I've recently moved from manually calling my Hasura client to using [Apollo-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module).

I added this under @Component

```js
apollo: {
    features: {
      query: gql`query { features { id, name } }`
    },
    tenants: {
      query: gql`query { tenants { id, name } }`
    },
    listings: {
      query () {
        return gql`${(this as any).buildListingsQuery()}`
      },
      prefetch: true
    }
  }
```

However it only fetches the data on page load, then when the query changes the data is lost and I have to manually refetch them creating a lag, also the loading option is lost so I can't use that one either. Any leads would help, thank you

Comment: You can maybe use `refetch()` on a `watcher` https://apollo.vuejs.org/api/smart-query.html#refetch

Comment: This one is probably more adapted if you're using the `<apollo-query>` component: https://apollo.vuejs.org/api/apollo-query.html#scoped-slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that goes through a similar issue, it was fixed for me by using the network for the fetch policy. I added

```
fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
```

Comment: This will never use the Apollo cache tho.